# How to recognize changes on digital inputs with read.fs in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I use `node.js` for programming an industrial raspberryPi. There are some digital inputs and outputs.
I can see the status of the inputs and write the outputs in `/dev/piControl0`.
Write an output is easy, because my JS code is calling a function to write the output, but how do I notice immediately when an input changed? I think using a timer to call the read function every x seconds is not a really well solution.

```js
var buffer = new Buffer.alloc(1);
fs.open('/dev/piControl0', 'r+', function (err, fd) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    }

    fs.read(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, 0, function (err, bytes) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }

        if (bytes > 0) {
            console.log(buffer[0])
        }
    });

    fs.close(fd, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the provided `.watch` [function](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) from the `fs` module for listening on the `change` event:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('./path-to-file', (eventType) => {
    if(eventType === 'change') {
        // file was changed, read content here
    }
});
```